# Reshape 3D numpy array of images to 2D numpy array for XGBoost DMatrix input

Tags: python, numpy, xgboost, numpy-ndarray

I've got a set of images in a 3D array (of dimensions index * height * width).

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, yy, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, stratify=y)
print(x_train.shape, x_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)

dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(data=x_train, label=y_train)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(data=x_test)
```

I get an error from XGBoost DMatrix input:

```
ValueError: ('Expecting 2 dimensional numpy.ndarray, got: ', (2164, 120, 431))
```

Shape of the arrays from the print above:

```
(2164, 120, 431) (542, 120, 431) (2164, 3) (542, 3)
```

I'm confused about how to reshape the data. Does it need to be 2164 rows * 1 column?

Comment: You might want to look at other kind of models for image data. Its not just that an XGBoost's input can't be 3D, its also not suited for image data (a simple reshape probably won't take you anywhere either). You might want to look into [CNNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried a CNN first with Keras, however I've got a small unbalanced dataset so results aren't great. ~70% accuracy. Someone suggested XGBoost might produce better results with that type of dataset. So I'm giving that a try. Is the flattening of the image, as user A Kareem below suggests, the issue?

Comment: It's just not the right tool really. If using a CNN didn't produce good results, you might want to look into why that is so, rather than trying classical ML classifiers. Tree based algorithms won't be able to learn much from image data. You need models that learn structure and meaningful 2D features. CNNs do so by applying filters to the image. They are the usual approach when it comes to image data

Comment: Thanks for the advice, much appreciated. I’ll take another look at the CNN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html?highlight=dmatrix#xgboost.DMatrix) it seems that X needs to be 2-dimensional, and Y needs to be 1-dimensional. Thus X needs to be of shape (index_of_sample, features) thus the width and height need to flattened into a single vector (this is not a good idea for images since you lose structural value but then again this must happen since the model is xgb)

Thus, you need to reshape X to be

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], -1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], -1)
```

Also, the documentation states that Y needs to be 1-dimensional. Thus you need to somehow change Y to be a categorical value instead of the current (I'm assuming) one-hot encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Just reshape your `x` numpy arrays.

`x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], -1)`

`x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], -1)`

Comment: For similar problem, mine is with LightGDM for prediction error and the issue appear s to be with the lgb.Dataset: my question is posted under: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75894373/lightgbm-prediction-issue-valueerror-input-numpy-ndarray-or-list-must-be-2-dime