# Lightgbm prediction issue TypeError: Unknown type of parameter:boosting_type, got:dict

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm

**Problem**

Build prediction accuracy model using lightgbm on New York Taxi Duration dataset. [Kaggle model:https://www.kaggle.com/code/mobilematthew/newyorkcitytaxidurationprediction/edit/run/123885887

Setting up Light Gradient Boost with one set of parameters, and two models, 1) use to LGBMClassifier fit / predict, 2) to to LightGB train / predict.

Tested 2) LightGB train / predict and this code works. Added 1) LGBMClassifier fit / predict, with exact same parameters, should work fine, but the fit raises an error.

The 2) model trains fine before this issue. The problem is when I attempt to make a prediction from the lightgbm 1) LGBMClassifier fit model. This is the error: "TypeError" which is raised from the lightgbm.fit() function. The y is one dimension. X_train has multiple features, all reduced via importance. To analyze this numpy.ndarray for 2 dimensions.

```
lgb_train = lgb.Dataset(X_train)
lgb_y_train = lgb.Dataset(y_train)
lgb_eval = lgb.Dataset(X_test, y_test, reference=lgb_train)

param_grid = {  'boosting_type':'gbdt',
                'n_estimators':50, 
                'objective': 'regression',
                'num_leaves': 5,
                'num_boost_round':20,
                'class_weight':'balanced',
                'colsample_bytree':1.0,
                'importance_type':'gain', 
                'learning_rate':0.001, 
                'max_depth':-1,
                'min_child_samples':20, 
                'min_child_weight':0.001, 
                'min_split_gain':0.0,
                'n_jobs':-1, 
                'verbose':0,
                'random_state':None, 
                'reg_alpha':0.0, 
                'reg_lambda':0.05, 
                'subsample':1.0, 
                'subsample_freq':0,
                'min_data':1,
                'force_row_wise' : True,
                'eval_set':[X_test, y_test]
            }

light_model = lgb.LGBMClassifier(param_grid,random_state=42)
light_model_fit = light_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
light_model_fix_y_pred = light_model_fit.predict(X_test)

light_model_trained = lgb.train(param_grid, lgb_train)
light_model_trained_pred = light_model_trained.predict(X_test)
```

**Code with raised error**

With above code, trained model, so far everything working fine

**Setup for prediction**

Setup light gradient boost fit for predict invocation, this is where the Value Error is raised.

```
light_model_fit = light_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

**Error**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_27/124012372.py in <module>
     30 
     31 light_model = lgb.LGBMClassifier(param_grid,random_state=42)
---> 32 light_model_fit = light_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
     33 light_model_fix_y_pred = light_model_fit.predict(X_test)
     34 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lightgbm/sklearn.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, init_score, eval_set, eval_names, eval_sample_weight, eval_class_weight, eval_init_score, eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds, verbose, feature_name, categorical_feature, callbacks, init_model)
    970                     eval_metric=eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds,
    971                     verbose=verbose, feature_name=feature_name, categorical_feature=categorical_feature,
--> 972                     callbacks=callbacks, init_model=init_model)
    973         return self
    974 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lightgbm/sklearn.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, init_score, group, eval_set, eval_names, eval_sample_weight, eval_class_weight, eval_init_score, eval_group, eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds, verbose, feature_name, categorical_feature, callbacks, init_model)
    756             init_model=init_model,
    757             feature_name=feature_name,
--> 758             callbacks=callbacks
    759         )
    760 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lightgbm/engine.py in train(params, train_set, num_boost_round, valid_sets, valid_names, fobj, feval, init_model, feature_name, categorical_feature, early_stopping_rounds, evals_result, verbose_eval, learning_rates, keep_training_booster, callbacks)
    269     # construct booster
    270     try:
--> 271         booster = Booster(params=params, train_set=train_set)
    272         if is_valid_contain_train:
    273             booster.set_train_data_name(train_data_name)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py in __init__(self, params, train_set, model_file, model_str, silent)
   2603                 )
   2604             # construct booster object
-> 2605             train_set.construct()
   2606             # copy the parameters from train_set
   2607             params.update(train_set.get_params())

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py in construct(self)
   1817                                 init_score=self.init_score, predictor=self._predictor,
   1818                                 silent=self.silent, feature_name=self.feature_name,
-> 1819                                 categorical_feature=self.categorical_feature, params=self.params)
   1820             if self.free_raw_data:
   1821                 self.data = None

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py in _lazy_init(self, data, label, reference, weight, group, init_score, predictor, silent, feature_name, categorical_feature, params)
   1515                 params['categorical_column'] = sorted(categorical_indices)
   1516 
-> 1517         params_str = param_dict_to_str(params)
   1518         self.params = params
   1519         # process for reference dataset

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py in param_dict_to_str(data)
    292             pairs.append(f"{key}={val}")
    293         elif val is not None:
--> 294             raise TypeError(f'Unknown type of parameter:{key}, got:{type(val).__name__}')
    295     return ' '.join(pairs)
    296 

TypeError: Unknown type of parameter:boosting_type, got:dict
```

**Data**

ValueError: Input numpy.ndarray or list must be 2 dimensional.

Data for this lightgbm model: 1 X_test, 2 X_train, 3 y_train 4 lgb.Dataset(X_train) via lgb.get[X] commands

X_test

```
    pickup_longitude    pickup_latitude dropoff_latitude    trip_duration   direction   week    minute_oftheday
139168  -73.990189  40.757259   40.762600   1095    69.265257   6   1289
1401881 -73.955223  40.768841   40.777191   390 39.910385   24  881
1207916 -73.955345  40.764126   40.781013   1171    -49.064405  1   1156
466038  -73.996696  40.733234   40.713543   1626    162.417522  14  683
855381  -74.004532  40.706974   40.717777   689 -5.260115   22  1237
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
425268  -73.978287  40.752300   40.763824   858 2.899225    23  900
940105  -73.984207  40.759949   40.751755   432 -166.399449 6   1084
502876  -73.970856  40.753487   40.764393   708 -11.675022  1   924
895439  -74.006882  40.710022   40.713509   486 -46.212070  5   682
699976  -74.002594  40.739544   40.778725   866 27.435443   25  1374
```

[image]

X_train

```
    pickup_longitude    pickup_latitude dropoff_latitude    trip_duration   direction   week    minute_oftheday
97650   -73.979507  40.765388   40.759701   600 -175.931831 19  1097
1101996 -73.970932  40.765720   40.762833   224 138.507110  8   1151
61397   -73.862785  40.768963   40.753124   884 -106.385968 8   1296
941058  -73.957634  40.782143   40.761646   1239    -136.690811 1   495
909725  -74.013771  40.701969   40.706612   240 51.439139   21  555
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
1054126 -73.990929  40.750561   40.728096   646 175.218677  17  549
624177  -73.941513  40.851059   40.849010   197 107.450422  25  559
1175512 -73.989532  40.769600   40.788155   413 40.718927   16  1316
823176  -73.982628  40.751122   40.754730   308 66.554445   19  1042
448716  -73.989456  40.720070   40.770935   969 61.479580   2   274
```

[image]

y_train

```
97650       600
1101996     224
61397       884
941058     1239
909725      240
           ... 
1234001     831
1403381    1590
454139     2226
557019      312
699873     1337
Name: trip_duration, Length: 2995, dtype: int64
```

[image]

Dataset X_train

```
,         ,pickup_longitude  ,pickup_latitude  ,dropoff_latitude  ,trip_duration  ,Direction,​week  ​     , ​minute_oftheday 
,97650,-73.979507,40.765388,40.759701,600,175.931831,19,1097
,1101996,-73.970932,40.765720,40.762833,224,138.507110,8,1151
,61397,-73.862785,40.768963,40.753124,884,106.385968,8,1296
,941058,-73.957634,40.782143,40.761646,1239,136.690811,1,495
,909725,-74.013771,40.701969,40.706612,240,51.439139,21,555
```

*Methods to get data from Lightgdm*

```
print(lgb_train.get_data())
print(lgb_train.get_feature_name())
print(lgb_train.get_label())
print(lgb_train.get_params())
print(lgb_train.num_data())
print(lgb_train.num_feature())
```

[image]

Comment: If you add a small example that can copy and paste to reproduce your problem it is much easier to help

Comment: OK LarryBird, added some short data samples from each: X_train, X_test, y_train, and the Lightgdm Dataset X_train

Comment: Thanks for adding more information, however it is still not really what I mean. You have explained more about your data, but I still see no code block I can copy and paste to quickly generate the data and reproduce your problem. For example, the block should in one place, contain all required imports, and only include the minimum amount of code that is required to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

light_model = lgb.LGBMClassifier(**param_grid) # the ** pointer reference is need to reference the param_grid list.

light_model_trained = lgb.train(param_grid, lgb_train) # this LBG train references param_grid without an explicit pointer reference.